# Android Studio shows error in v21/styles because of "android:" prefix

Tags: android, material-design, android-styles

I created a new project and there wasn't a v21 folder so I created one, added the "styles" file also and now after writing my style, I'm getting an error because of the "android:" prefix.

my code:

values/styles.xml :

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/maincolor</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/statusbar</item>
</style>
```

values-v21/styles.xml:

```
<resources>
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/maincolor</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/statusbar</item>
</style>
```

Android Studio marks "android:colorPrimary" and "android:colorPrimaryDark" as an error, it says "requires API level 21 (current min is 14)"
The app runs but my style won't show... What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What version of Android Studio? I tested with 1.1 and 1.2 Beta 3, and neither shows validation errors.

Comment: Android Studio 1.2 Beta 3

Comment: Just to be sure... The folder is called `values-v21` and not simply `v21`, right?

Comment: yes, called it "values-21" and inside it "styles"

Comment: I've edited your question so it's clear what folder/file you do reference to. Now, two questions, what is minimum API version of your project? And is the error reported on `values-v21/styles.xml` or on `values/styles.xml` ?

Comment: minSdkVersion is 14 and the error is on values-v21/styles.xml